# Can you do contactless card payments with a mobile app not tied to a user bank account?

Tags: payment

I was looking whether it is possible to pay with a mobile app like a bank card. Without the user being tied to it so funds can come from anywhere, maybe a payment platform or a company bank account (limited to what the user is allowed to spend according to the app).
Is this even possible? I can't find anything on it.

Comment: Your question is "Is it possible to transfer money to a company's bank account if I don't have a bank account?". The answer is no. If the money comes from "a payment platform", the company that runs the platform is a bank. How could they legally take user's deposits otherwise?

Comment: As in not the user's bank account, it can be tied to **a** bank account, owned by the developer of the app.